# Series $\sum_{d \geq 0} \sqrt{d} \cdot z^d$

Tags: analysis, power-series

As stated in the title, I'd like to compute the series $\sum_{d \geq 0} \sqrt{d} \cdot z^d$ where $z$ is a (small enough) complex number. More generally, for any **real** value $\alpha$, is there a general method to compute the series
$$
  \begin{equation}
    \sum_{d \geq 0} d^{\alpha} z^d
  \end{equation}
$$

When $\alpha$ is an integer, the series can be easily computed by combining differentiation and integration relatively to $z$. But for fractional $\alpha$, I don't know ...

Thank you !

Comment: To answer what "small enough" means here, the radius of convergence of this series is $1$.

Comment: we are talking about polylogarithms here. check out wikipedia:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm